# Let $T$ and $T'$ be two topologies on $X$ , $T \subset T'$. Show that if $T$ is a $T_1$ Topology , then $T'$ is also a $T_1$-topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $T$ and $T'$ be two topologies on $X$ ,  $T \subset T'$. Show that if $T$ 
is a $T_1$ Topology (resp. Hausdorff topology), then $T'$ is also a $T_1$-topology 
(resp. Hausdorff topology).

---

can anybody help me please to solve this problem.thanks for your time.

Comment: This is extremely straightforward. Suppose that $T$ is $T_1$. What exactly do you have to prove in order to show that $T'$ is also $T_1$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x, y \in X$. The fact that the topology $T$ on $X$ is $T_1$ implies that there are sets $U, V \in T$ with $x \in U$, $y \notin U$, and $y \in V$, $y \notin V$. Now if you consider instead the topology $T'$ which contains, all the sets that $T$ does, can you find two sets in $T'$ which satisfy the same conditions that $U$ and $V$ do?